# Migrating anonymous session data and restricting it to authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Right now the session data for anonymous (non-authenticated) users of my web application is not moved/assigned to the user once they log in or register.

For example: An anonymous user interacts with the application, creates some session data (say products in a shopping cart), then logs in/registers and then logs out, the session data is still accessible and is not moved/made inaccessible to the now unauthenticated user.

I am using file session driver (no database), perhaps someone could provide some example of what needs to be changed (I presume in Session config) in order to make any session data created by an anonymous user become assigned to and only accessible by this user once they authenticate by logging in or registering and only while the user is authenticated.

The requirement for this is because users of the application create unique objects (tied to their user_id) which are only persisted after payment when order processing runs. I store them in session until the user logs-in/registers and goes through with the final order step and only then are they persisted. So I absolutely can't have user specific objects retained in non-authenticated sessions after the user logs out. I could flush the session on logout, but ideally I want to keep them for when the user logs back in.

Answer (score 4):

The authentication system just uses the session as storage to persist authentication state across requests. However, Laravel's authentication system **is not responsible** for handling **all** your session data, it only cares about storing authentication related information, such as user details. If you want to handle additional session data for authenticated users, you need to do that manually.

The logic is simple:

- If a user does some action like adding something to a shopping cart, the data stays there as the session is bound via cookies to the browser from which the requests are coming from.
- If a user logs in from that same browser, Laravel's authentication system checks the credentials and if they are correct it stores the necessary information about that user in the same session. The previously stored data about the shopping cart is still there and untouched, so you can use it in the context of the logged in user. If at this point you want to persists the session cart so it's available for the user when he accesses his/hers account in the future, then you need to store the details in the database. Below are a few steps showcasing a way to achieve that:

**1.** Create an event listener, let's name it `SyncShoppingCart`, that will listen to the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` event (the double backslashes in the command `\\` are needed to escape a single slash):

```
php artisan make:listener SyncShoppingCart --event=Illuminate\\Auth\\Events\\Login
```

**2.** The previous command created a file in `app/Listeners` named `SyncShoppingCart.php`. Now you just need to stores the cart data in the  user's in the `handle` method of that class. The example below assumes you have `cart_item` table that stores informations about items added to the cart, and you have a `CartItem` model defined for it. This example is simplified and you will need to modify it to suit your needs, but it's a good starting point for understanding this approach:

```
public function handle(Login $event)
{
    // Iterate over the session cart items and 
    foreach (session()->get('cart') as $item) {
        $cartItem = new App\CartItem();

        // Set the user ID for the cart item so you know
        // which user added this item to the cart
        $cartItem->user_id = Auth::id();

        // Set the product ID and any other properties
        // you want stored for the cart item
        $cartItem = $item->product_id;
        // ...

        // Save the cart item to the database
        $cartItem->save();
    }

    session()->forget('cart');
}
```

**3.** Then register the even listener in the `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php` within the `$listen` array:

```
protected $listen = [
    ...
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\SyncShoppingCart',
    ],
];
```

Now whenever the user logs in, the `App\Listeners\SyncShoppingCart::handle` method will be called and will add the items from the session cart to the database. Of course after a user is logged you should store new items added in the database as well, the session alone should be used to store cart info just for guests. On logout you can remove the cart from the session and be done with it, knowing that the cart contents are stored in the database and can be retrieved the next time the user logs in.

---

You can read more about [Authentication Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#events), [Sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session) and [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events) in the Laravel Docs.

Comment: I don't simply wish to remove the cart session data after the authenticated user logs out. I want it to remain but now ONLY be accessible to that user when they authenticate/log-in again. So, if an anonymous user adds products to cart and then logs-in/authenticates and then logs out, the session data stays, but is now only accessible to that user when they are authenticated. Similarly, if an authenticated user adds products to the cart and then logs out, all session data for the cart stays, but is only accessible once the user logs back in.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding how sessions work. Sessions are transient and are only good at storing information while the user is browsing the website, and as I mentioned in my answer a session is bound to a browser. So even if you set sessions to expire after 10 years (not a good thing to do), and you stored info in that session it would work only in the one browser which holds the session ID in the cookie, if the user logged in with the same account from another browser that session would not be available. If you want to persist cart information you need to store in the database.